# immutable objects in node should be declared let, var or const? is there some difference?

Tags: node.js, immutability

The following code build an immutable object:

```
Object.freeze({ "foo" : "bar" })
```

Is there some difference in creation using

- var
- let
- const

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that

```
const foo = Object.freeze({ "foo" : "bar" });
```

cannot be later reassigned with

```
foo = 'baz';
```

While `var` and `let` can.

Immutability is orthogonal to reassignment. There may be a need for a variable that stores immutable object to be reassigned, there may be a need to store mutable object in `const`.